# What does the phrase "taking a bath with the crowd" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I recently heard the phrase "taking a bath with the crowd" and that apparently it's a common idiom in many European languages.  I found several results for the phrase on Google, but none that explain what it means.  Does anyone know what the phrase means, and if there's a common (American) English phrase that means the same thing?

Comment: I have never heard of an idiom that is the same across languages, as you suggest. And certainly not taking a bath with the crowd, which is not an English idiom.

Answer (score 4):

Stéphane's suggestion, “to mingle with the crowd”, may well reflect the intended meaning of the speaker of the phrase.  But note that in English, the phrase  “take a bath” often is associated with a stock-market loss ([1](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/takeabath.asp#axzz27JcCF7zw), [2](http://www.davemanuel.com/investor-dictionary/take-a-bath/)); since the European idiom is not well-known in the U.S., I'd expect American English speakers to either associate your phrase with taking a loss in the market (along with a crowd of other investors) or to interpret the phrase literally.

Answer (score 2):

It means “to mingle with the crowd” or maybe a bit more faithfully  to “immerse oneself in the crowd” (as suggested by StoneyB in the comments).

The original idiom is closer to “taking a bath of crowd” (in French at least).
Just as if the world were a container filled with human beings.

Comment: Is this Baudelaire's " Il n'est pas donné à chacun de prendre un bain de multitude"?

Comment: Baudelaire uses a variation here. “Un bain de foule” is the usual and very common idiom.

Comment: But does the idiom predate Baudelaire, or does it derive from "Les Foules"?

Comment: Interesting question. I would not trust these figures too much, but [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+bain+de+foule%2C+un+bain+de+multitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) suggests that these phrases appeared around Baudelaire's time.

Comment: Hmm ... well, if you can trust Google Books (you can't!), the only citation for "bain de foule" before B's time is [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=onI7AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=%22un+bain+de+foule%22&source=bl&ots=jT9aOAdpGP&sig=Cs9bMPWaKBwf6WdfjiP9PLgQMbM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6kxfUO39LunJyQHz4IGYBw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22un%20bain%20de%20foule%22&f=false). (The other  one it finds, labeled "1833", is in fact dated 1889.) Perhaps B was indirectly punning on the term from vintage?

Comment: "immerse oneself in the crowd" might get closer to the literal idiom. I find it translated "[go] walkabout" a lot, but that's not AE either.

Comment: Yes that's a good suggestion. *Immersion* fits well together with the idea of “taking a bath”.

Comment: @StoneyB: *Foule* in this [ngram example](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+bain+de+foule%2C+un+bain+de+multitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) doesn't mean "crowd". "La foule" can also be [the fulling of cloth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulling), that's what it means here. And "le bain" in this example is the actual liquid in which the fulling takes place. [Alain Rey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Rey)'s *dictionnaire culturel en langue française* gives 1960 as first appearance of the phrase "*bain de foule*" as meaning "to mingle with the crowd".

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: I did not check all the links in your ngram, but those I checked up to the 1960s use "*bain de foule*" for the liquid in which the fulling (*foulage* in French) of cloth takes place.

Comment: @Laure  Fulling - that makes a lot more sense (I looked it up and got 'pressing', from winemaking; my French is very much after the school of Stratford-at-Bow). My question was whether perhaps the technological phrase triggered Baudelaire's use of 'bain' in this context, or if he was even punning with it.

Comment: @StoneyB. I don't think you share anything else with Madam Eglantyne, though, or do you?

Comment: @Paola  Well, I don't eat gravy with my fingers.

Comment: @StoneyB: I strongly doubt Baudelaire was punning with the homonymy of the word. Not only because making puns is not his style, he probably did not think about it. I could add a little more on the origin of the word *foule* ("crowd") but this is not the place. Why don't you ask a question on FL&U?

Comment: @Laure: Here it is: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/3218/79

Answer (score 1):

It means "to suffer (take a bath) by doing what the crowd is doing" (in stocks, real estate, tulips, whatever). In my book, "A Modern Approach to Graham and Dodd Investing," I noted that every few years, lemmings will gather in large groups, "travel," and "upon reaching their destination, they will all jump into the sea, and of course, drown." The consolation for the fact that they all die is that "every lemming that dives into ocean gets to retire in the same style as every other lemming that does the same."

Answer (score 1):

It means when a politician wants to show he is popular, and leaves the security perimeter around him to get close to the crowd surrounding that perimeter. It comes with risks, as French president Emmanuel Macron found out when he was recently slapped by a man in June 2021.